# Get stream from piped subprocess in async with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio

I would like to run the following commands directly in `Python`:

```
dumpcap -q -f http -i eth0 -w - | tshark -l -n -T json -r - | my_app.py
```

I would like to run it by using `subprocess` and `asyncio` for having it run in `async`.

So at first I would like to run:

```
dumpcap -q -f http -i eth0 -w -
```

The output from this should be piped into the next command, which should/could run unsynchronized:

```
tshark -l -n -T json -r -
```

The output from this should be piped into a stream which I can work with.

Is there a straightforward solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @user4815162342's answer, note that you can simply pass the full shell command to [create_subprocess_shell](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.create_subprocess_shell) and use pipes to communicate with both ends of the subprocess:

Example:

```py
proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
    "tr a-z A-Z | head -c -2 | tail -c +3",
    stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
)
stdout, _ = await proc.communicate(b"**hello**")
assert stdout == b"HELLO"
```

Comment: `proc.communicate()` will attempt to read all of the data instead of streaming line-by-line. this is bad for memory use (imagine if you expect the child stdout to be larger than main RAM) and bad for performance (processing the first line won't happen until the child has finished)

Comment: @inetknght Sure, it really depends on the command being run. For instance, `communicate()` is fine if the command already includes some aggregation and produces a small output (e.g `tail -n 1`, `wc`, etc.).